# Change background color in list menu

Tags: android

I'm building a simple app with a listmenu from a video tutorial by The new Boston 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zjHYyAJQ7Vw&list=EC2F07DBCDCC01493A And in that lesson you create this listmenu without any layout. It's all working for me, almost, the menu is in the activity, but I can't see any text in the menu. The text is visible just when i press on one of the menues option. The background is always white when I run my apps on the AVD or my phone.

Is there a way to change the background color and the color of the text, when you create an listmenu in an activity without the layout.xml? Or could there be something else that is wrong? Preciate som help. Thanks!

EDIT: I'm not sure if it's the background color of the activity or the buttons in the menu?It's all white and the text is also white, but there is a gray line between the options in the menu. I'm not sure the answers below will work, since I don't use any xml layout file with a listview? Perhaps it's better to do it with a xml lyaout file instead? Preciate some further help!

EDIT: Added some code:

```
public class Menu extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"MainActivity", "Example1", "Example2"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Menu.this,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, classes));
}

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String selectedClass = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.test.theNewBoston." + selectedClass);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Menu.this, ourClass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: it is easer to change it on xml , you can use `selector` xml, very easy

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it is better to use a normal Activity than ListActivity.

```
ListView list  = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    //ListView parent, View v, int position, long id 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    }
});
```

and you can set the background color like this:

```
list.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

try like this by applying selector. It will helps you to change background color.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <item android:drawable="@color/pink" android:state_pressed="true"/>

        <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>

    </selector>
```

Comment: this will helps you to change the background color of the item which you clicked.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class HttpEx extends ListActivity {

    String options[] = {"BasicConnect","ConnectToSql","TBA","TBA",
                        "TBA","TBA"};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, options));
        getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //add this code into the onCreate
    }
```

This is how I got the background color to change for my ListActivity.
getListView().setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK); //add this code into the onCreate

Answer (score -1):

you can change the background for listview on java like this

```
yourlistview.setBackgroundColor(color)
```

For click on each item in you `ListView` you can change the `BG` in two ways:

First. add on `item click listener` to your `ListView` list this:

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    //ListView parent, View v, int position, long id 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        arg1.setBackgroundColor(Color.Black);
    }
});
```

Second. Use `Adapter` to your `ListView` and then add clicklistener on the `GetView` for each item

I think the first way is better